How to find the file that contains the code of an R function?
I have R 4.3.2 installed on my Windows PC. I downloaded it from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/. I have not downloaded the .tar.gz file with the R source code.
I know how to view the code of a function. If I type chisq.test in the console, for example, I get the code for the chisq.test function. This is a base function from the package stats.
The thing is: that code shown in the console must be stored somewhere, in some file on my computer. The code could not be displayed if it were not so.
Where is it? Is it a general method to find such locations?
I really tried to find it with no results. It's nowhere in C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2. I uploaded it to a GitHub repository and searched chisq.test and got no results either. I also looked in other folders in the same hard drive and found nothing. I didn't find anything useful on stackoverflow either.
I expect the code to be stored somewhere.

As mentioned by @StephaneLaurent in comments, a standard installation of R doesn't include the source code in a human-readable text format; it's instead in a binary format that is more convenient for R to unpack.
From the console/terminal window, R RHOME will give you R's home directory (provided R is in your path so that it can be found ...) Starting from this directory, changing to library\stats\R will show you where the code actually lives. Unfortunately, the package code is stored as two binary files, stats.rdb and stats.rdx. This question asks how to open .rdb files (not trivial). These files are more thoroughly described in the section on "Lazy loading" in the R internals manual. (This article by Brian Ripley explains what "lazy loading" is, why it is useful, and how R uses the rdb/rdx machinery.)
It would be more practical to either download and unpack the R source code from CRAN (and navigate to src/library/stats/R/chisq.test.R), or to look at the corresponding file on the r-svn Github mirror (or on the official R Subversion server).

That's a good answer. So if I understood correctly, the code for chisq.test and the other functions in stats are stored in stats.rdx and stats.rdb (mainly in the latter). These are binary files, which are also compressed, so they cannot be read directly. R has a method to decompress and express this information in plain text, and that how the code gets displayed in the console when I type chisq.test. Am I right?

Yes, that's right.

I have accepted the answer, but I have a new doubt.  Do the .rdb files have anything to do with the functions being byte-compiled? I was reading this question, and I was wondering if the stats functions were byte-compiled into the stats.rdb file, if that makes any sense.

It's a separate issue. The primary reason to store the data in this format is so that R can have access to pointers to the individual objects (functions and data) in the package, but not need to load the objects until the user actually tries to do something with them. This saves the overhead of loading all of the functions in a (potentially very large) package because the user wants to use just one of them. (See the article I've now linked to in my answer.)

You can execute the function .libPaths() to get the file paths where your packages are installed. One of those folders is for user-installed packages, and other is for base packages, like {stats}. This answer is based on this StackOverflow answer.
Another option is the R.home() function, which will return the path of your R installation. In that folder, the library directory contains base packages, such as {stats}.
The {lookup} package also allows you to browse function definitions, including compiled code, S3 and S4 methods:
# install.packages("devtools")
# devtools::install_github("jimhester/lookup")

library(lookup)

lookup(chisq.test)

lookup::lookup_usage("chisq.test")


You can also browse R's source code in the GitHub mirror

I read that post previously. If I write .libPaths() in the console, I get the path "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.3.2/library". However, the code of chisq.test is not there...

Please read my updated answer

The package looks interesting and a very good option to quickly find the source code of R functions based on compiled C functions. It is an automatic way to search the code in the source code repository. But I already knew how to find it in the repository (manually, slowly and with a lot of patience). However, I still don't know how to find more basic R code locally on my PC.
Moreover, I tried to install the package, but I get an error: Error: Failed to install 'lookup' from GitHub:   Failed to install 'highlite' from GitHub:   ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed

You won't find the R code in the package folder. The R code is compiled.

@StéphaneLaurent If it is compiled, how is it possible to see the code of chisq.test in the console?

@FranciscoJácomeMaura I don't know. But if you don't believe me, use a text finder to scan the folder, and you will see there's no R code.

R stores the parse tree (and sometimes the source as well).  For base functions, it's almost always just the parse tree.  What you are seeing is the result of calling "deparse()" on that parse tree.  (You don't see any comments, do you?)  If the source had been stored, it would be stored in a compressed form, so even that is hard to find using external tools.

I wonder if it is possible to find the code of compiled function in R's source code

@user2554330 Thats looks compelling. However, I'm not familiar with parse trees. As @BenBolker points out in his answer, the code appears to be into a compressed binary file (stats.rdb) and is difficult to obtain. But when accessed, the code does not contain comments. What does the parse tree has to do with the .rdbfile?

The parse tree is a representation of the code.  For example code 1 + 2 # comment would be represented as a pairlist containing (+, 1, 2) (with the comment completely omitted).  f(x) + g(y) would be more complicated, something like:  (+, (f, x), (g, y)).  The .rdb file contains a binary version of one pairlist for each object in the package environment, concatenated together.  The .rdx file tells R where to find each one.  (This is oversimplified.  Many objects have attributes, some objects refer to other objects, etc.)
